# How to Render a Page using Ajax and Radio Buttons on Rails 3.2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2, radio-button

I'm trying to render diferent forms for each type of tool inclusion on my system. I wish i could do this in a simple way, so i tried:

View:

```
<span><%=  radio_button :tool, :tool_type_id, "1", :onclick =>  "render_partial();" %>Common Tool</span>
<span><%=  radio_button :tool, :tool_type_id, "2" , :onclick => "render_partial();" %>Special Tool</span>
<span><%=  radio_button :tool, :tool_type_id, "3" , :onclick => "render_partial();" %>Ferramenta Calibravel</span>
 </fieldset>
<div id="partial-area" style="display:none;""></div>
```

My Application.js:

```
function render_partial() {
  $('#partial-area').css('display','block')
  if ($("input[name='tool[tool_type_id]']:checked").val() == '1') {
    $('#partial-area').html('<%= escape_javascript(render ("form_tt1"))%>')
  } else if ($("input[name='tool[tool_type_id]']:checked").val() == '2') {
    $('#partial-area').html('<%= escape_javascript(render ("form_tt2"))%>')
  } else if ($("input[name='tool[tool_type_id]']:checked").val() == '3') {
    $('#partial-area').html('<%= escape_javascript(render ("form_tt3"))%>')
  } else {
    $('#partial-area').html('<b> Please select a tool through Radio Button </b>')
  }
}
```

This works, but not to render, when i click over the radio i only get the string 
`<%= escape_javascript(render ("form_ttX"))%>`

I walked through google but I couldnt make it work, can someone help?

Comment: if it's a radio button then only one can be selected at a time. Why not have the onclick event for each

Comment: Vornoi, Actually this is not the problem, javascript code works ok, what happens is, when i click over the radio, instead the javascript gives back the rendered page, it renders the string     <%= escape_javascript(render ("form_ttX"))%>